# SwaggerUI in java springboot project with jjwt keeps throwing 403 status codes

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, openapi, swagger-ui, jjwt

I have a java springboot maven project where I want to have some sort of automatic client code generator that'll create my client side code. I firstly have to use openAPI/swagger to document my api, generate the json of this information and then generate the client-side code. The issue is I implemented jwt using the version 0.12.3 of jjwt and every time I try to access any swagger endpoints (eg: `http://localhost:9090/auto-pass/v3/api-docs`) a 403 status code gets thrown and I have absolutely no idea why (btw my context path is `auto-pass`)

I first tried every different swagger and openAPI dependency and settled with these

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I  then tried to tweak my security configs a whole bunch to try to ignore the endpoints I'm accessing

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/signup", "/api/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auto-pass/v3/api-docs", "/auto-pass/v2/api-docs", "/auto-pass/swagger-resources/**", "/auto-pass/**", "/auto-pass/swagger-ui.html", "/auto-pass/v3/api-docs/**", "/auto-pass/api-docs/**", "/auto-pass/api-docs", "/auto-pass/index.html", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v2/api-docs", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

I thought maybe just adding a bunch of these endpoints I found all over stack overflow would work but nothing ever resolved my problem.

I also thought about possibly needing a swagger config class but most documentation online on openAPI stated that anything other than putting the mvn dependency is only optional and that the swaggerUI html page should still be shown.

Also I was messing with openAPI codegen plugins earlier and I get this warning, not sure if it has to do with the swagger UI html page generation but I thought it'd be of use :

```
2024-01-01T16:02:58.778-05:00  WARN 37572 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.MustacheAutoConfiguration      : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
```

This is run when running the maven command, `verify -f pom.xml`

I'm at a point where I don't exactly know where to go. A little earlier today the `http://localhost:9090/auto-pass/v3/api-docs` This URL for accessing the JSON file for the docs were accessible but the SwaggerUI was never. I'm also having a hard time finding quality docs as a lot of java libraries are deprecated for newer undocumented ones (or atleast less documented).

Thanks alot for the help and happy new year :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the API using postman, if it works then it's problem of your spring security configuration not swagger.
If it works on postman but not on swagger, compare the CURL of both requests, and there must be something which is missing in the swagger. Most probably the jwt token you are passing isn't being passed on to the API correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, I finally got everything to work. I used refresh tokens with secure tokens in my final solution. I took off any context paths and was finally starting to see the **Swagger UI**. I was missing some endpoints in my security config and I also needed to add `@SecurityRequirements()` in my auth controller to remove security requirements. Then I started getting some 401 on all endpoints. I had to ignore these in the JWT auth filter. [Github Repo](https://github.com/Raaphe/AutoPass)